# When importing coordinate data into My Maps (Google) layer I want to set the image path to Google Drive

Tags: google-maps, spreadsheet

I have a Google Spreadsheet with coordinate data and a path to an image in a Google Drive folder, I want to import the spreadsheet into a map in My Maps and tell the importer that the column [IMAGE] is the path for the Placemark image. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the following

1. Create a kml file with your placemarks from the spreadsheet
2. Create a folder for images, and place your icons there
3. Edit the kml file and create icon styles (referencing your images), and assign it to your placemarks as:

```
    <Style id="icon-ci-2-labelson">
          <IconStyle>
            <scale>1.1</scale>
            <Icon>
              <href>images/icon-2.png</href>
            </Icon>
          </IconStyle>
    </Style>
```

4. Pack everything into a kmz file (compress the KML file and images folder, name it with extension kmz) as in https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmzarchives
5. Import your kmz file as a layer to My Maps and enjoy.

Comment: The problem is that i want to add a description image for de Placemark and for some reason the solution that you propose is not working for My Maps