# Add photo to Google My Maps with image path in spreadsheet

Tags: photos, google-mymaps

I used Google Sheets to add points in Google My Maps. I know it is possible to add an image to the points. However, I have more than 600 points and I wonder if it is possible to add photos via image path in the spreadsheet?

Unfortunately, they are not geotagged...

Comment: If you mean add image to placemark icon, i already proposed a solution packing images in a kmz file and uploading it to My Maps if it's helpful https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/425692/when-importing-coordinate-data-into-my-maps-google-layer-i-want-to-set-the-ima/425700#425700

Comment: Google My Maps is your only option? I know a way to do what you are asking but in Google Earth

Comment: Well, we are relatively limited in technical possibilities. I only want to publish coordinates with a name and a photo at each point and then implement this in a website. I found google sheets as a practical solution. But I am also fine with KMZ, or any other easy way. https://www.baumnaturdenkmal.at/webmap/

Answer (score 0):

I have done this with an HTML+JavaScript page that "creates" kml code, reading a Google spreadsheet for populating the "kml text", here is the code and you have to put your own structure, and you can use simplehttpserver, I made a little script for waking the web server, you can find it at the end

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
    <title> Spreadsheets to KML </title>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Google Sheets to KML </p>

    <button id="authorize_button" style="display: none;">Autorizar</button>
    <button id="signout_button" style="display: none;">Salir</button>

    <pre id="content" style="white-space: pre-wrap;"></pre>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        //Client ID and API key from the Developer Console
        var CLIENT_ID = 'YourGoogleCloudClientID';
        var API_KEY = 'YourSheetsApiKey';

        //Array of API discovery doc URLs for APIs used by the quickstart
        var DISCOVERY_DOCS = ["https://sheets.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v4"];

        //Autorization scopes required by the API; multiple scopes can be included, separated by spaces.
        var SCOPES = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly";

        var authorizeButton = document.getElementById('authorize_button');
        var signoutButton = document.getElementById('signout_button');

        /**
         * On load, called to load the auth2 library and API client library.
         * 
         */
        function handleClientLoad() {
            gapi.load('client:auth2', initClient);
        }

        /**
         * Initializes the API client library and sets up sign-in state listeners
         */
        function initClient() {
            gapi.client.init({
                apiKey : API_KEY,
                clientId : CLIENT_ID,
                discoveryDocs : DISCOVERY_DOCS,
                scope : SCOPES
            }).then(function (){
                //Listen for sign-in state changes.
                gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.listen(updateSigninStatus);

                //Handle the initial sign-in state.
                updateSigninStatus(gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.get());
                authorizeButton.onclick = handleAuthClick;
                signoutButton.onclick = handleSignOutClick;
            }, function(error) {
                appendPre(JSON.stringify(error, null, 2));
            })
        }

        /**
         * Called when the signed in status changes, to update the UI
         * appropriately. After a sign-in, the API is called.
         */
        function updateSigninStatus(isSignedIn) {
            if(isSignedIn) {
                authorizeButton.style.display = 'none';
                signoutButton.style.display = 'block';
                listPatrollingPoints();
            } else {
                authorizeButton.style.display = 'block';
                signoutButton.style.display = 'none';
            }
        }

        /**
         * Sign in the user upon button click.
         */
        function handleAuthClick(event) {
            gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signIn();
        }

        /**
         * Sign out the user upon button click
         */
        function handleSignOutClick(event) {
            gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signOut();
        }

        /**
         * Append a pre element to the body containing the given message
         * as its text node. Used to display the results of the API call.
         * 
         * @param {string} message Text to ve placed in pre element.
         */
        function appendPre(message) {
            var pre = document.getElementById('content');
            var textContent = document.createTextNode(message + '\n');
            pre.appendChild(textContent);
        }

        /**
         * Print the Date and Coordinates in a spreadsheet:
         * https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/YOURSHEETID/
         */
        function listPatrollingPoints() {
            gapi.client.sheets.spreadsheets.values.get({
                spreadsheetId : 'YOURSHEETID',
                range : 'SheetName!Range',
            }).then(function(response) {
                var range = response.result;
                if(range.values.length > 0) {                                                
                    appendPre('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>');
                    appendPre('<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">');
                    appendPre('<Document>');
                    appendPre('<Folder>');    
                    for (i=0; i<range.values.length; i++) {
                        var row = range.values[i];
                        appendPre('<Placemark>');
                        appendPre('<name>'+ row[1] + '</name>');    
                        appendPre('<description><![CDATA[<img style="max-width:500px;" src="'+ row[4] +'">Inspector:'+ row[3] +']]></description>');                            
                        appendPre('<Point>');
                        appendPre('<coordinates>');    
                        appendPre(row[7] + ', ' + row[6] + ', 0');
                        appendPre('</coordinates>');
                        appendPre('</Point>');
                        appendPre('</Placemark>');
                    }
                    appendPre('</Folder>');
                    appendPre('</Document>');
                    appendPre('</kml>');
                } else {
                    appendPre('No data found');
                }
            }, function(response) {
                appendPre('Error: ' + response.result.error.message);
            });
        }

        </script>

        <script async defer src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js" onload="this.onload=function(){};handleClientLoad()" onreadystatechange="if(this.readyState == 'complete') this.onload()">
        </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The tiny script (cmd script) for the web server is (im assuming that only reading it you will know what im talking about, so if you have doubts only ask):

```
@echo off
python -m http.server.8000
```

From here you access to the web page by the URL http://localhost:8000/
and copy the text with MKL structure to a empty file named doc.kml. You must have the image folder in the same folder of the KML file, then you can add the doc.kml file and the image folder to a zip file, then the generated zip file must be renamed with the kmz extension.